# How to send PDF as html and read it with $_POST superglobal

Tags: php, forms, pdf, fdf

This should be very easy, yet it's not working. I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction because I kind of hate adobe documentation, and on adobe community forums I guess I hardly will get a straight answer. Anyway, the thing is I've created a fillable form in Acrobat X, and added a button with a submit form action, with the url pointing to my php script. When I view the form in any browser, and submit it, I can see it gets submitted because the network part of the developer tools shows the POST request and everything, with a response code of 200 OK. Yet all I can get from the $_POST superglobal is a notice telling me the indexes I point to do not exist. I've checked thoroughly and those indexes are really the names of my fields on the pdf form. Also, oddly the form is not replaced by the script in the browser, but it stays in the same url. It's driving me crazy because from what I've read everywhere on Google it's supposed to be the way to do it.

my script goes like this (as if it was interesting):

```
$apes = $_POST['Apellido_Nom'];
$dir = $_POST['Direccion'];
$fp = fopen('formulario.txt', 'w+');
fwrite($fp, 'Nombre, '.$apes.'Dirección, '.$dir);
while(!feof($fp)) {
$buffer=fgets($fp, 4096);
echo $buffer;   
}
fclose($fp);
```

Please don't mind the manners of this question, it's just I've had a really rough day. Oh and by the way I also set the export format of the pdf form as html.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` Let's see what's actually in that joker.

Comment: thanks Nicholas, I actually did that and the output was array(0), strange, ¿huh?

Comment: Then your PDF form isn't submitting any data to your PHP script. Your submit button on your PDF must not be configured properly. Dump the GET variable while you're at it to check.

Comment: I wish to say that I tried to read thoroughly the javascript developer guide for Acrobat from adobe and I found it pretty obscure. I read most about submitting forms and tried to deal with the mailForm and submitForm methods but they seem to be bound to the app, and though they talk of things as if they were very easy, it's really hard to make things work out of the 'determined' flow of Acrobat itself. It's just an opinion about propietary software

Comment: Nicholas: the $_GET variable echoes array(0) as well. I think I ran into a swamp here. I can't seem to find what the problem is. My button was configured from Acrobat using the actions panel in the properties of it, and writing the full path with http protocol in it, and I've also tried writing #FDF at the end of it (something I read somewhere) without any result

Comment: @Nicholas Pickering However it's kind of late. If I find the solution I'll post it and message you. Thanks.